# How to use Toast Notification while the app is running on Windows Phone 8.1 Runtime App?

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, toast

I'm working on a budget manager app. My app records expense and income as they are input by the end user. But I wanted to add a functionality to the app : users would be able to add an income/expense that would happen on a regular basis (like every 10 days for example).

I thought that ScheduledToastNotification was the solution to this problem since I wanted the user to approve the creation of this transaction for the process to complete. But the problem is that when the app is running (even running from the background) when the ToastNotification is shown on the screen, tapping it does not work like intended : launch parameter is not passed to my app. I figured out that the reason to that is because the OnLaunched event is not fired (because the app is running).

Another problem is that I can't make sure that everything is working fine since I can't debug such behavior : ToastNotification is only relevant when the app is not running, but I can't debug a not running app. So how can I know exactly what happens when I launch my app through a ToastNotification ?

Is there any solution that can help me achieve this goal ? Below is my code :

```
public static void CreateNotification(Class.Action Transaction)
    {
        var loader = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.ResourceLoader();
        var ToastXml = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(ToastTemplateType.ToastText02);
        var Strings = ToastXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");
        Strings[0].AppendChild(ToastXml.CreateTextNode(loader.GetString("NotificationText")));
        Strings[1].AppendChild(ToastXml.CreateTextNode(Transaction.Title + " : " + Transaction.SAmount));

        IXmlNode toastNode = ToastXml.SelectSingleNode("/toast");
        XmlElement audio = ToastXml.CreateElement("audio");

        audio.SetAttribute("src", "ms-winsoundevent:Notification.IM");
        toastNode.AppendChild(audio);

        ((XmlElement)toastNode).SetAttribute("launch", Transaction.Id.ToString());

        var Toast = new ScheduledToastNotification(ToastXml, Transaction.NextOccurence);

        Toast.Id = Transaction.Id + "";

        ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().AddToSchedule(Toast);
    }
```

And this is how I intend to use the parameter :

```
int TransactionID = 0;

        if (int.TryParse((string)e.Parameter, out TransactionID))
        {
            var loader = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.ResourceLoader();

            Class.Action RecurentAction = new Class.Action((from act in ActCRUD.GetActions()
                                                                where act.Id == TransactionID
                                                                select act).FirstOrDefault());

            Flyout flyer = new Flyout();
            StackPanel content = new StackPanel();

            TextBlock editMessage = new TextBlock();
            editMessage.FontSize = 20;
            editMessage.Margin = new Thickness(15, 50, 15, 15);
            TextBox newCategoryName = new TextBox();
            newCategoryName.FontSize = 20;
            newCategoryName.Margin = new Thickness(15, 15, 15, 15);
            Button confirmEdit = new Button();
            confirmEdit.Margin = new Thickness(15, 15, 15, 15);

            editMessage.Text = loader.GetString("EnterComment");
            newCategoryName.PlaceholderText = loader.GetString("EnterCommentPlaceholder");
            confirmEdit.Content = loader.GetString("OkText");
            confirmEdit.Tapped += new TappedEventHandler(delegate(object o, TappedRoutedEventArgs i)
            {
                RecurentAction.Comment = newCategoryName.Text;
                ActCRUD.AddAction(RecurentAction);
                MainPage.CreateNotification((from Class.Action action in ActCRUD.GetActions()
                                             orderby action.Id descending
                                             select action).First());

                flyer.Hide();
                newCategoryName.Text = "";
            });

            content.Children.Add(editMessage);
            content.Children.Add(newCategoryName);
            content.Children.Add(confirmEdit);

            flyer.Content = content;

            MessageDialog NotificationConfirmation = new MessageDialog(loader.GetString("ConfirmRecurentAction"));
            NotificationConfirmation.Commands.Add(new UICommand(loader.GetString("Confirm"), (commands) =>
            {
                flyer.ShowAt(PivotFintatanana);
            }));

            NotificationConfirmation.Commands.Add(new UICommand(loader.GetString("DoNotConfirm"), (commands) =>
            {

            }));

            await NotificationConfirmation.ShowAsync();
        }
```

What I'm looking for is a ScheduledToastNotification that would send its parameters to the app even when this one is running (by forcing it to fire OnLaunched event or through other workarounds).

Thanks,
Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the toast is shown while the app is running, and if you tap on the toast, the `OnLaunched` function is indeed called. However, the code in `OnLaunched` provided by Visual Studio template checks if content of `rootFrame` is `null`, and if it isn't (which should be the case if your app is running), it simply shows the running instance.

Here is the code which is skipped if the app is already running:

```
if (rootFrame.Content == null) //shouldn't be null if app is running
{  
    if (!rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments))
    {
        throw new Exception("Failed to create initial page");
    }
}
```

So you need to add your logic in this portion of code, something like

```
if(e.Arguments != null)
{
    //navigate to details page with e.Arguments
}    
else if (rootFrame.Content == null)
{
    if (!rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(BlankPage1), e.Arguments))
    {
        throw new Exception("Failed to create initial page");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Abhishek ! This definitely solved my issue. Just for the records : this is my very first question on this site. So double thanks :)